# Is it possible that TeamViewer just updated itself to version 15? How to prevent this?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

Suddenly today my TeamViewer connection to the remote computer stopped working because of incompatible versions! It was still working on Sunday 24th.

My local computer has version 14.2 (on Win XP). The remote computer now has version 15 (on Windows 10) . I am not able to connect to it from the computer any more. Only from mobile TeamViewer app (seems impossible to figure out its version). Is it possible that TeamViewer has just updated itself on the remote machine in last two days?

That would be really bad behaviour. How do I disable this? I do not see any setting in the options which would relate to automatic updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Advanced options, on the General advanced settings"section, try setting "Install new versions automatically" to `No automatic updates`.

In case you don't want it to check for new updates, then set "Check for new version" to `Never`.